# NodeJS with Mongoose Find-query not returning correct result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoose schema with static methods, but and when I run:

```
model.statics.specialMethod = function(id, callback) {
return this.find({to_lock:id},callback);
}
```

It returns only property _id and to_lock. Why? Default setting is to include the whole document. Is it some bug? When I use other tools than NodeJS, it returns the correct values.

Thank you

Comment: Could you add `specialMethod` code please?

Comment: Its there, the declaration of the static method of the model

Comment: I meant, could you add the code where you are using `specialMethod`?

Comment: I use it like this:

model.specialMethod(123, function(err,result) {
console.log(result);
});

But I have a second problem, when it actually returns a value, after som tweaking with quotes etc in the find()... It only returns 1 out of 2 documents.

Comment: Please edit your question with complete data model.